# Help identify this ceramic capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I am trying to rebuild the circuit in the Toyota Supra electric mirror. There are yellow ceramic capacitors that don't seem to conform with any of the identifying marking I can find.
Can anyone tell me what I need to replace them with?[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is a capacitor?  What is the part designation on the board?

Comment: Looks more like a protection device like a MOV to me ...

Comment: Check the spelling in your post title.

Comment: The board only comes hidden away in the depths of the wing mirror. It works as it should if I connect 12v direct across the motor. If i use the circuit connections it does not. All i have is what i can see. From its function it must allow power through whilst the mirror folds back and then as it reaches the full fold or open it uses the relay to shut off power to the motor to stop it burning out.

Answer (score 2):

It might be a 0.5A/60V PTC (resettable fuse). If it is in series with the power and measures low resistance it's probably okay.

Shotgun replacing of parts is not usually a good plan.

Comment: 60R050X Littlefuse